# Ruby - detecting the end of the read file

Tags: ruby, file, upload, eof

I upload through a form a file and in the controller this file read. My problem is, that I don't know, hot to detect the end of the file (=> when stop a loop). This part of code looks like this:

```
dat = params[:data]
while(d = dat.read)
  puts d
  break if d.eof #this doesn't work
end
```

The result of this part is (except the error about **eof**) infinity while looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-read:

If length is omitted or is nil, it reads until EOF and the encoding conversion is applied. It returns a string even if EOF is met at beginning.

So I guess you should just do `dat.read`

Edit: if you want all the lines of the file, use `dat.readlines` - this will return an `Array` of `Strings`

Comment: And watch out on large files!

Comment: "And watch out on large files!", yes. Feeding that code a couple GBs of data should make the server slow down.

Comment: thanks for replies guys. I forgot to add I need to read the uploaded file line by line, because I need to save every line of the file into DB.

Comment: `dat.each` or `dat.lines` would give you the file line by line.